# Netty optimising latency

Tags: java, performance, tcp, io, netty

I've been developing a proxy with netty 4.0 (Alpha 8). Everything is well, currently I need to optimize the latency, effectively I send strings with around 4000 bytes from NY to London. I zip the payload with the JZlib encoder over a delimited frame decoder.

I do that in comparison to a proprietary tool, so I have a benchmark, currently I measure from a thirdparty interface until I put it to a netty channel this process is in submilliseconds to 3-5 milliseconds range for both sides, client/server. On the server I use the time from message received until i send it out to the thirdparty interface.

In betweeen the transmission time ranges from 200 - 500 ms and outliers in the below 100 ms, 1 second and 2 second range.

At the moment I am using oio since there is only one permanent connection from the client to server, I use tcp no delay. Traffic is heavy, I am sending marketdata information.

At the moment I want to continue to remote profile the app, get gcc logging going and either locally or on the servers try to sniff the packages and compare the thirdparty traffic with the one I am currently generating over netty.

My questions:

- What is the outmost point in netty that I can use to measure the time used in my component which uses netty, so for the client and server, is it channel.write and messageReceived?
- Given this scenario what other Channel options should I try to improve performance?
- Using wireshark has anyone advise on which package properties to look for (I know it is a general question and I will compare the packages at first instance).
- Should I use some other callbacks or diagnostic help provided in netty?

Thank you very much for your advise.

I was able to solve it and the results were great. Even though for a low number of connections the advise given in some articles were to use oio I switched to nio this resulted in below 100 ms transmission results for mostly all transmissions.